# How to make a variable with a list of multiple values

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is make a variable that has more than 1 value. so if someone types either "value1" or "value2" it'll return as the variable.

my script for this portion is:

```js
var multiply = "x", "*"
```

it returns:

```js
var multiply = "x", "*"
                    ^^^

Syntax Error: Unexpected String
```

is it possible for me to do this, or what is the correct way?

Comment: You may want to look into [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two [easy] ways to do this.

1. You can use Arrays

```js
let multiply = ["x","*"];
console.log(multiply);
console.log(multiply[0], multiply[1]);
```

2. you can use an object

```js
let multiply = {
  value1:"x",
  value2:"*",
};
console.log(multiply);
console.log(multiply.value1, multiply.value2);
```

The second option is *closer* to what you were asking for with the user typing value1 and value2, however as seen they must prefix it with "multiply."

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this

```js
let val = "x";
var multiply = val || "*";
console.log(multiply); // output will be x
```

```js
let val = "";
var multiply = val || "*";
console.log(multiply); // output will be *
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to store multiple values into variable then we should be using array

var list = ["x", "*"]

Answer (score -1):

Use arrays to store multiple values in a single variable.

`var list = ["x", "*"]`

and you can call the value using indices.

`list[0]` will return `"x"` and likewise `list[1]` returns `"*"`